# Text in tables are all out of the place

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I was coding this little page here

http://burnhabbo.com

But then my friend and a big range of friends of his use old XP computers (wth) with this resolution size (1024x768) and when they access the page, all the text in divs is outside the middle box all way to right.

Here's all the CSS and

```
#playerb {
    position: absolute;
    left: 740px;
    top: 507px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
#song {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(190, 190, 190, 1);
    font-size: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 554px;
    top: 538px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 60px;
}
#listeners {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(190, 190, 190, 1);
    font-size: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 696px;
    top: 538px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 60px;
}
#myhabbo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 518px;
    top: 511px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

the DIVs

```
<div id="playerb">
    <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://burnhabbo.com/play.html"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="myhabbo"> <a href="http://habbo.com.br/home/T.Moonblade" target="_blank"><img     src="img/avatarimage.gif" width="33" height="56" title="Sup noobs!"/></a> 
</div>
<div id="song">
    <marquee>
        <a href="https://93.190.141.194:2199/tunein/burn.pls" id="cc_strinfo_song_burn" class="cc_streaminfo" style="text-decoration: none">Carregando...</a>
    </marquee>
</div>
<div id="listeners">
    <span id="cc_strinfo_listeners_burn" class="cc_streaminfo"></span>/3000
</div>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to the problem of developing for different screen resolutions.  After you finish this, enjoy the "Developing for different browsers" speech down the hall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen your page structure, and it isn't really good...

You have to study more html and css to position your content better.

I recommend you to use `div`s for this particular work, and also to spend a lot more time on understanding css. (In particular background css.)

Here a [link](http://w3schools.com/css/) with some additional information.

I made an example of good structure for you. This is the HTML:

```
<div class="back">
<h2>Leiam caros usuários!</h2>
<p>Por este meio viemos comunicar, que nós, a BurnHabbo virá para ficar na família
   dos sites habbo e promete arrasar os seus pixeis! Estamos num servidor dedicado
   localizado em França segurado por uma firewall costumizada e avançada, e contamos
   com o apoio de vários programadores freelancers profissionais paracriar a nossa 
   versão e painel.
   AVANTE BURN HABBO!</p>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.back{
  color:white;
  height:233px;
  width:434px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-image:url('http://burnhabbo.com/img/aviso.png');
  background-position:top center;
  text-align:center;
}
.back h2{
  padding-top:5px;
}
.back p{
  padding:0px 20px;
  margin-top:-10px;
  font-size:18px;
}
```

See also [this live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HPEWG/).

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so muuuuuch!! I'm going to have a read on w3schools then, I already knew the site but only searched for it when I needed a snippet or two. Now my next task is to align the player